# how to send the Sequential request in custom services module

Tags: hooks, commerce, 7

I have two request 
1. /............./endpoint/retrieve
2. /............./endpoint/create

In this case 'retrieve' request only working, if i am send the request as 'create' it's call the same callback function, but i am using different callback function in this following code

This is my hook_services_resources

```
function module_rest_services_resources() {

  return array(
    'new_note' => array(
      'retrieve' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'module_rest'),
        'callback' => '_module_rest_retrieve',
        'access callback' => '_module_rest_access',
        'access arguments' => array('view'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
    ),
      'create' => array(
           'help' => 'Creates a note',
           'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'module_rest'),
           'callback' => '_module_rest_create',
           'access arguments' => array('create'),
           'access arguments append' => FALSE,
           'args' => array(
             array(
               'name' => 'data',
               'type' => 'int',
               'description' => 'The note object',
               'source' => array('path' => '0'),
               'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

what i need to change in this code, to access the both 'retrieve' and 'create'

Comment: You don't need to change anything. How are you coming to the conclusion that the same callback is running for both resources?

Comment: yes, retrieve callback function only calling for both request.

Comment: What I mean is, how do you know that? Are you stepping through the code in the request? Putting debug code into your callbacks? Services most definitely respects the callback you tell it to use, so either you have a broken version of services, or you're mistaken about which callback is running

Comment: Give me some idea to solve this problem.

Comment: I am using debug code in my callbacks.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to get a working version of the Services module. Code similar to yours works perfectly for me, the resource callbacks are never mixed up. Try disabling any add-on modules to Services you may have installed too (eg commerce services) to make sure they're not causing the problem

Comment: But it's working for first callback function correctly(retrieve).  using version core = 7.x
php = 5.x

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem so I can't really help any more than what I've already suggested. Like I say, similar code works for me so the problem must be coming from something in your specific installation/configuration

Comment: sorry too.. i am not installed the any commerce services module.help me , i am fresher for drupal